# R, Why does my factor show up in a different order than the way I typed it?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I feel stupid for asking this but a quick google search led me back in a loop of "why didn't you try it the way you did try it?" so here goes, please point me to where this has been asked already if I just missed it:

I have data like this:

```
df<-structure(list(participant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), satisfied_6 = c(1, 1, 7, 7, 6, 6, 1, 
9, 1, 6, NA, 1, 8, 8, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

And I want to turn "satisfied_6" into a factor when graphing.  So I've done this:

```
df%>%filter(!is.na(satisfied_6))%>%mutate(satisfied_6=as.factor(satisfied_6))%>%mutate(satisfied_6=fct_recode(satisfied_6,"Never"="1","Rarely"="6", "Sometimes"="7", "Often"="8", "Always"="9"))
```

And it kinda works, turns "satisfied_6" into a factor and gives it those levels.  Problem is, the order of the levels I want is the way I typed it:  Never, Rarely, Sometimes, Often, Always.   The levels in the graph go:   Never, Sometimes, Rarely, Always, Often   and that's the same order as when I say:

```
  levels(df$satisfied_6)
```

So the "levels" are different from both the order of the numbers and the order I typed it in. So two questions:    is something wrong with my code?  And/or how do I correct that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's `dput` shows the data as `rowwise` grouped, so it may be better to `ungroup` before doing any other operations.  Also, the renaming and ordering can be done within the `factor` call itself.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
        ungroup %>%
        filter(complete.cases(satisfied_6)) %>%
        mutate(satisfied_6 = factor(satisfied_6, levels = c(1, 6, 7, 8, 9),
           labels = c("Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Always")))
```

-output

```
> levels(df1$satisfied_6)
[1] "Never"     "Rarely"    "Sometimes" "Often"     "Always"
```

---

Or if we want to use `forcats`, just add the `ungroup` in the OP's code and it should work

```
library(forcats)
df1 <- df %>%
       ungroup %>%
       filter(!is.na(satisfied_6))%>%
       mutate(satisfied_6=as.factor(satisfied_6))%>% 
        mutate(satisfied_6=fct_recode(satisfied_6,"Never"="1",
          "Rarely"="6", 
        "Sometimes"="7", "Often"="8", "Always"="9"))
> levels(df1$satisfied_6)
[1] "Never"     "Rarely"    "Sometimes" "Often"     "Always"
```

Comment: How did you recognized that data is grouped rowwise?

Comment: @TarJae you can check the `str(df)` or if you just type `df`, it shows the Rowwise attribute .e. `df
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Rowwise:`..

Comment: @TarJae Before doing anything, I always check the `str` to understand the data